# Dynamically Enable/Disable Mat-Selection-List Mat-List-Option

Tags: angular-material

I have the following mat-selection-list. I need it to enable the options in a cascading fashion. i.e. The Second Selection will not be enabled until the First Selection is selected. The Third Selection will not be enabled until the Second Selection is select, etc...
[image: SelectCriteria]


Here is the html code for the list:

```
 <mat-selection-list id='selectedParameters' [(ngModel)]="selectedCriteria">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of incomingParameters" [selected]="item.selected" [value]="item.name"
        [disabled]="item.disabled" checkboxPosition="before" (click)="GetChange(item)">
        {{item.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Here is how I populate the List:

```
    if (this.data.criteria.FirstSelection) {
        arr.push({
            name: 'First Selection',
            selected: false,
            disabled: 'false',
        });
    }

    if (this.data.criteria.SecondSelection) {
        arr.push({
            name: 'Second Selection',
            selected: false,
            disabled: 'true',
        });
    }

    if (this.data.criteria.ThirdSelection) {
        arr.push({
            name: 'Third Selection',
            selected: false,
            disabled: 'true',
        });
    }

    if (this.data.criteria.FourthSelection) {
        arr.push({
            name: 'Fourth Selection',
            selected: false,
            disabled: 'true',
        });
    }

    if (this.data.criteria.FifthSelection) {
        arr.push({
            name: 'Fifth Selection',
            selected: false,
            disabled: 'true',
        });
    }

    if (this.data.criteria.Sixth Selection) {
        arr.push({
            name: 'Sixth Selection',
            selected: false,
            disabled: 'true',
        });
    }
```

How can I cascade the enabling/disabling of the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question, here is my solution, get the length of the selected array and enable those that are less than the value!

html

```
<h1 class="mat-headline">MatSelectionList</h1>
<h2 class="mat-subheading-1">Input compareWith is not triggered</h2>
<mat-selection-list
  #matSelectionList
  [compareWith]="compareServiceTypes"
  [(ngModel)]="data"
  (ngModelChange)="uncheck($event)"
  multiple
>
  <mat-list-option
    checkboxPosition="before"
    [value]="s.id"
    [selected]="data.includes(s.id)"
    *ngFor="let s of serviceTypes; trackBy: s?.id; let i = index"
    [disabled]="i > getMax()"
  >
    {{ s.label }}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

{{ data | json }}
<div class="mat-small material-version">
  @angular/material: {{ version.full }}
</div>
```

ts

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelectionList, VERSION } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('matSelectionList') matSelectionList: MatSelectionList;
  version: any;
  data: any;
  serviceTypes = [];

  constructor() {
    this.version = VERSION;
    this.data = [];
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.serviceTypes = [
        {
          id: 1,
          label: 'Service type 1',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Service type 2',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          label: 'Service type 2',
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          label: 'Service type 2',
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          label: 'Service type 2',
        },
      ];
    }, 1000);
  }

  uncheck(value) {
    let found = null;
    this.serviceTypes.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (
        (this.data[index] || this.data[index] === 0) &&
        item.id !== this.data[index] &&
        !(found || found === 0)
      ) {
        found = index;
      }
    });
    if (found || found === 0) {
      this.data.splice(found);
    }
  }

  getMax() {
    return this.data.length;
  }

  compareServiceTypes(st1: any, st2: any) {
    console.log('compareServiceTypes');
    // const result = st1 && st2 ? st1.id === st2.id : st1 === st2;
    return st1 && st2 ? st1.id === st2.id : st1 === st2;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-selection-list-5wgxab)